# implementing variable identification in shunting yard algorithm

Tags: java, expression, evaluate, shunting-yard

This is a follow up to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639109/evaluating-an-expression-in-string-form-containing-variables-in-java) question.
at this point I want the program to identify the variables by itself and then ask the user for variable values .so instead of looking like:

```
Enter an Expression: 

ADD(DIV(SIN(FACT(X1)),CEIL(TAN(MUL(1.5,FIB(X2))))),GCD(Y,10))     

Enter Variables: X1,X2,Y    
Enter values for X1, X2 and Y by this order(separate the values by space): 3 4 2    
The Result is: 1.94
```

the program should function like :

```
Enter an Expression: 

ADD(DIV(SIN(FACT(X1)),CEIL(TAN(MUL(1.5,FIB(X2))))),GCD(Y,10))     

your variables are : X1,X2,Y    

now Enter values for X1, X2 and Y by this order(separate the values by space): 3 4 2    
The Result is: 1.94
```

so the user no longer needs to tell the machine what the variables are.
how can achieve this?

I have checked [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490164/identifying-variables-in-equation) question but it's quite different from what I need and also it's in python

UPDATE: specifically I want to iterate shunting yard algorithm so it can find the variables. I've put a link for the parser code below
http://paste.ubuntu.com/9999494/

Comment: You need to write a parser.

Comment: When you create a parse tree for your equation, you check, for each token which is an identifier whether it is a known one (e.g. function name or known constant like π). If not, mark it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the names of all your functions, and then look for all arguments which are neither functions nor numbers.

So when you scan the input `ADD(X, DIV(3, Y))`, it should detect that `ADD` and `DIV` are functions and 3 is a number. This leaves X and Y, which must therefore be variables. Basically, whenever you detect a bracket, you should look for the matching closing bracket, then split the contents of those brackets at the commas and evaluate each part. If a part is neither a number nor a function, it must be a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following algorithm:

1. Split the text into tokens separated by '(', ')' or ','
2. Search through the tokens filtering out known functions and numbers
3. Everything remaining is a variable

Here is a possible implementation using Java 8 streams:

```
List<String> getVariables(String expression, List<String> functions) {
    return Collections.list(new StringTokenizer(expression, "(),")).stream()
        .map(Object::toString)
        .filter(token -> !functions.contains(token))
        .filter(token -> !token.matches("\-?\d+\.?\d*"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer 
by the way how can I implement this to shunting yard algorithm from EvalEx that I'm using for parsing ?
this is the code
http://paste.ubuntu.com/9999494/